# Javascript is not executing before form submit

Tags: javascript, django, forms

I currently have a form, with two buttons, "add" and "submit".
Using javascript, I'm adding more rows to the form whenever "add" is clicked.
However it does not update the form until I click "submit". How do I get it to add the rows without hitting the "submit" button?

```
<form method="post" id="formset">
<table>
{% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
{{ formset }}

<div id="empty_form">
<tr>
{% for field in formset.empty_form.visible_fields %}
<td>{{ field }}</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
</div>
</table>
<button id="add_more" type="button">Add</button>
<button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#add_more').click(function() {
var form_idx = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
$('#formset').append($('#empty_form').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_idx));
$('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_idx) + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

look into `target.oninput = functionRef;`
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput

example:

```js
let input = document.querySelector('input');
let log = document.getElementById('log');

input.oninput = handleInput;

function handleInput(e) {
  log.textContent = `The field's value is
      ${e.target.value.length} character(s) long.`;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Type something here to see its length." size="50">
<p id="log"></p>
```